# Generic type not infered in list operations OCaml

Tags: list, types, ocaml

While trying to find a certain sequence in a list I came up with the following:

```ml
type 'a sequence = {
  pos : int;
  mutable count : int;
  seq : 'a list;
}

let rec all_seq_for seq len pos = 
  match seq with
  | [] -> []
  | _::xs -> 
    let length = List.length seq in
    if length > len then 
      List.append {pos = pos; count = 1; seq = (sublist seq 0 (len - 1))} (all_seq_for xs len (pos +1)) 
    else if length = len then 
      seq 
    else
      []
```

the line `then List.append {pos = pos...` throws the Error: `This expression has type 'a but an expression was expected of type 'b list`
I don't understand why the type of `'a sequence list` is not automatically inferred.
How can this error be solved?

Comment: Not an answer, but a possible optimization suggestion: you don't actually need to know the `length` of `seq`. You just need to know how it compares to `len`. If you use `List.compare_length_with` your code may (when it compiles) run a bit faster.  `match List.compare_length_with seq len with 1 -> ... | 0 -> seq | _ -> []`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual error says this:

```
Error: This expression has type 'a sequence
       but an expression was expected of type 'b list
```

which is a crucial difference.

You are supplying a record as the first argument of `List.append`, but the first argument should be a list. Possibly you should just enclose your expression `{ ... }` in square brackets: `[ { ... } ]`.

Or maybe the error is deeper than that; I thought `'a sequence` was just a description of what you're looking for. If so, it doesn't make sense to append it to a list (it seems to me).